# Start app at a specific page whenever app is suspended WP 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 (non SL) application.

My app has multiple views, these are `Page01.xaml`, `Page02.xaml` and `Page03.xaml`.

How can I get my app to get back to `Page01.xaml` whenever the app is **suspended**?

So for example, the user is on `Page02.xaml` and he is interacting (doing whatever he wants), then he suspends the app. When he gets back to my app, I want him starting at `Page01.xaml` instead of where he was!

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App.xaml.cs you have method which triggers when app is called from tombstoning. In this method you can remove from RootPage's stack all pages and navigate to Page01.

@edit:

```
Window.Current.Activated += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
     var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

     if (rootFrame.BackStack.Count > 0)
     {
         rootFrame.BackStack.Clear();
         rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page01));
     }
};
```

Comment: can you please provide the code needed to do this? How do I remove pages from the RootPage stack?